# Dusseldorf Weeze Airport to Stuttgart by night

Tags: budget, germany, transportation, airport-transfer, nrn

We will arrive at Dusseldorf Weeze airport (NRN) at 23:10.

How can we reach Stuttgart during the night and at a reasonable price?

Comment: Hi Gabriela, welcome to travel.SE. First, what happens at 23.10? Is it your landing time or the time you can be waiting for a train to Stuttgart? Also, "cheap" is too vague, what do you expect (some people may consider taking a cab will be cheap enough)?

Comment: Is hiring a car and driving a suitable option? Or would you prefer something like public transport?

Comment: Sorry for not enough details.Will land at 23.10 so after 24 let's say will need a transportation.Cheap will be like 30 euros pr person.Train, bus, public transportation will be very good.

Answer (score 3):

> How can we reach Stuttgart during the night and at a reasonable price?

You can't (unless you rent a car). That airport is 70km away from Düsseldorf in the middle of nowhere, and calling it "Düsseldorf Weeze airport" is basically false advertising.

There is a free shuttle service to the nearby Weeze and Kevelaer train stations, and a bus to Düsseldorf main station for 14 EUR, but only a single train to Stuttgart (at 2:47, with easy to miss connections) until next morning. See http://bahn.de for details.

My suggestion would be to spend a night in the [airport hostel](http://www.airhostel.de/) and make your way towards Stuttgart at your leisure the next day. However, a budget of 30 EUR per person to get to Stuttgart is only possible if you use the [Quer-Durchs-Land-Ticket](http://www.bahn.de/i/view/USA/en/prices/germany/quer-durchs-land-ticket.shtml) which is restricted to regional trains and requires chaging trains a lot (5 or 6 times between Weeze and Stuttgart).

Comment: @Gabriela The preferred SE way to say ‘thank you’ is to upvote or accept an answer.